# Using bootstrapping random.choice

Tags: python, numpy, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrapping to make 1000 replications of the sons (np.random.choice) for resampling with replacement, so that i can calculate the mean for each replication. Then I would compare the standard deviation of these mean values ​​with standard.

However I don't get bootstrapping part right, how to fix that?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats

df = pd.read_csv('http://www.math.uah.edu/stat/data/Pearson.txt',
                 delim_whitespace=True)
df.head()
y = df['Son'].values

Replications = np.random.choice(y, 1000, replace = True)
print("Replications: " , Replications)
print("")
Mean = np.mean(Replications)

print("Mean: " , Mean)

sem = stats.sem(y)
print ("The SEM : ", sem)
```

Comment: Are you by any chance looking for `Replications = np.array([np.random.choice(df.Son, len(df), replace = True) for _ in range(10000)])`?

Comment: `np.mean(Replications, axis=1)`?

Comment: Thanks that what i was looking for, i guess  you added 10000 one 0 by mistake ?

Comment: You're welcome! I added the comments as an answer. And yes, I accidentally added an extra zero. Just took it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create 1000 replications of length `len(df)` each as follows:

```
Replications = np.array([np.random.choice(df.Son, len(df), replace = True) for _ in range(1000)])
Mean = np.mean(Replications, axis=1)
print("Mean: " , Mean)
```

Thanks!