# What's the most efficient way to resample from an array many times and take the mode of each sample?

Tags: python, numpy

So bootstrapping, but for modes.

The end goal is to create a probability distribution out of these modes. I need to create a test statistic that compares these distributions (and then perform a permutation test), so the initial bootstrapping needs to be as quick as possible so that creating the null distribution doesn't take too much time.
Can I use numpy's random.choice for this?

Comment: So you want to bootstrap and then calculate the mode of each sample?

Comment: That's right—and of course, the "resamples" should be the same size as the original sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting from [Using bootstrapping random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982819/using-bootstrapping-random-choice)

```py
import scipy.stats as ss

array = ...
num_samples = 1000

sample_size = 100

Replications = np.array([np.random.choice(array, sample_size, replace = True) for _ in range(num_samples)])
mode_result = ss.mode(Replications, axis=1)

mode = mode_result.mode
```

Comment: Just to clarify, does the "mode" variable now contain the modes of each of the resamples?

Comment: Yeah, [stats.mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) applies along the axis, so it returns a list of both the mode and count, but you can access just the mode with `mode.mode`

Comment: Another clarification: shouldn't mode.mode consist of num_samples modes? So in this case, there should be 1000 different modes to represent each of the 1000 samples we've taken? Right now it looks like we're only returning len(array) number of modes...

Comment: @AnthonyPetruzzio That was just a copy-paste error from the original source. I added a variable to control the number of elements in each sample

Comment: I mean shouldn't the resulting mode variable consist of 1000 samples here? Instead, it only consists of the length of the array. Try, for example, array = [1,2,3] to get a sense of what I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249846/discussion-between-dash-and-anthony-petruzzio).